# Module import of .sorted object from async-await functions return empty array [object] properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, module

When generating a filtered and sorted list, my initial document returns a perfectly populated array of objects and properties.

However, if I import that into another document to run further operations, the array returns empty properties, despite using async/await and Promise.all to fulfill all promises from the previous exported function.

Here is my exported function from the filter and sort:

```
export async function V2V2SORT() {
  try {
    const dexdata = await COMPAREV2V2();
    const dexdatafilter = dexdata.filter((item): item is any => (item !== undefined && item.v2a.reserve0 > 10 && item.v2b.reserve1 > 10));
    const dexdatasorted = dexdatafilter.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.diffPercent - a.diffPercent;
    })
    console.log(dexdatasorted)//DEBUG
    return Promise.all(dexdatasorted);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  };
}
V2V2SORT()
```

And here is my imported function, which only attempts to aggregate 3 similar arrays into one:

```
import { V3V2SORT } from './dexdata/V3V2SORT/V3V2SORT';
import { V2V2SORT } from './dexdata/V3V2SORT/V3V2SORT';
import { V2V3SORT } from './dexdata/V3V2SORT/V3V2SORT';


export async function dexSort() {
    let v3v2 = await V3V2SORT();
    let v2v2 = await V2V2SORT();
    let v2v3 = await V2V3SORT();
    const alldex = [] as any;
    alldex.push(v3v2);
    alldex.push(v2v2);
    alldex.push(v2v3);
    console.log(alldex);
    return alldex;
}
dexSort()
```

My import data appears like this:

```
  [
    {
      pair: [Object],
      v3: [Object],
      v2: [Object],
      diffPercent: 460.92231367298285,
      direction: [Object]
    },
    {
      pair: [Object],
      v3: [Object],
      v2: [Object],
      diffPercent: 0.22076681012417426,
      direction: [Object]
    }
  ]
```

I assume there is a clue in the fact that the diffPercent properties carry through properly, while all other data is scrubbed.

If I log results to console from within V2V2SORT() using `console.log(dexdatasorted)` I get expected results. When I import them and attempt to put them into a single array in DEXSORT(), I receive an empty array; except for the diffPercent property which reads fine.

Comment: Why do you export and run the function in each module?

Comment: Why do you `return Promise.all(dexdatasorted);`. dexdatasorted is not an array of promises

Comment: I'm aggregating them into a single array organized by difference in percentage in descending order. 

That may not be the most efficient way to do it... but either way it should still resolve with the data included as properties.

Comment: re: return Promise.all(dexdatasorted):
That may have been added as an attempt to sort the problem, but with/without it doesn't change the result nor throw an error.

Comment: Anyone capable of answering this, or just people having stylistic issues?

Comment: Sorry, it's not a "stylistic issue" ... I was merely trying to figure out what it is you think you're trying to achieve - can you explain (show) what it is your result actually is - currently, I understand it like you receive *"an empty array, except it has some data in it"* - so please, given the input data you've shown, show the result

Comment: you're also checking if `item.v2a.reserve0 > 10` and `item.v2b.reserve1 > 10` - yet your input data has no such properties - again, this isn't a stylistic issue, it's a *your question makes no sense* issue

Comment: I appreciate your attempts to understand my question. `item.v2a.reserve0 > 10` and `item.v2b.reserve1 > 10` were filters that didn't find any matches in the provided dataset, but they did exist eventually in the original.

I should have been more simplistic with my question: "Why am I receiving [object] as properties in my imported object?" would have been a better framing of the question, for which the answer could have been, "Because you're importing an array, which requires specifying object keys, etc" or something to that effect. 

I just didn't understand the problem, initially.

Comment: My question turned out to be a misunderstanding of node passing in objects vs. arrays of objects.

In the end, I was able to receive the required data by simplifying my code to import the object, without re-formatting it into an array:

`export async function dexSort() {
   let v2v3 = await V2V3SORT();
   let v2v2 = await V2V2SORT();
   let v2v2 = await V2V2SORT();

   console.log(alldex);//<--prints all the data

}
dexSort()`